# Show a group $G$ of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices with coefficients modulo $13$ has seven subclasses and prove it has 3 normal subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, normal-subgroups

> Let $G= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \text{ with } a \text{ in } \{1,3,9\} \subset F^{*}_{13} \text{ and } b \text{ in } F_{13} \right\}$, where $F^{*}_{13}$ is the group modulo $13$ under multiplication and $F_{13}$ the group modulo $13$ under addition. Show it has seven conjugacy classes with respectively $1,3,3,3,3,13,13$ elements and prove it has exactly three normal subgroups.

I started this problem by looking at the conjugacy classes, that is for $g_{1}g_{2}g^{-1}_{1}=g_{3}$ for some $g_{1} \in G$.

> Thus I let $g_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $g_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} c & d \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$ then $$g_{1}g_{2}g^{-1}_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} c & -bc+b+ad \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now per conjugacy class this needs to be an element of $G$. So I guess I have to check the order per assigned value of $c, a, b$ and $d$. Correct? Now $c$ can either be $1,3,9$, thus let's start with

$c=1 \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & ad \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, now $a$ can be one of three things but $d$ can be any of $13$. So I would argue this conjugacy class already has $3 \cdot 13 = 39$ elements. Obviously I go wrong, but where and why?

I don't even know where to begin to argue it has exactly three normal subgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjugacy class containing element $g \in G$ is defined as the set of elements $g'$ such that there exists $h \in G$ satisfying $g' = hgh^{-1}$. The thing you've done wrong is allow $g_2$ to vary within the same conjugacy class; this is not always allowed.

What you want to do here is pick a *fixed* $g_2$, and then find all possible elements of the group of the form $g_1 g_2 g_1^{-1}$.

The conjugacy class with one element is simply the identity matrix. Also note that the top-left element of the matrix $g_1 g_2 g_1^{-1}$ is the same as that of $g_2$, so every element in the same conjugacy class has the same top-left element. Note that if $c \neq 1$, the top-right entry is $b(c-1) + ad \in F_{13}$. Since $13$ is prime and $c-1 \neq 0$, we simply let $b$ vary over $F_{13}$, and note that $b(c-1)$ must take every value modulo 13 since multiples of a nonzero number in a prime mod take every value in that mod.

So we can obtain every possible top right entry, and so the set of elements in $G$ with a top-left entry of $3$ form a conjugacy class, and the set of elements with a top-left entry of $9$ form another conjugacy class. This gives us the two classes of size $13$.

It remains to divide the twelve elements remaining into conjugacy classes. The top-right entry is now $ad$, for fixed $d \neq 0$ and $a = 1, 3, 9$. Clearly this yields three distinct values, and so each element remaining is in a conjugacy class of size $3$. This completes the first part.

To find normal subgroups, note that the entire $G$ is clearly a normal subgroup, as is the trivial group only containing the identity matrix $I$. The third normal subgroup is the set of elements with $a=1$; note that this is a subgroup as the top-left element of $g_1 g_2$ is $1$ for any $g_1, g_2$ in this subgroup, and note that it is normal because the conjugate of any element in this subgroup still has top-left element $1$ and therefore is contained in the subgroup.

We now need to prove there are no other normal subgroups. Let the normal subgroup with all elements $a=1$ be called $A$. Now any non-identity element in $A$ can be repeatedly multiplied to itself to yield all elements of $A$ (try proving this), so any normal subgroup containing any non-identity element in $A$ must contain $A$ itself. Also note that for any element $g$ not in $A$, the elements $g$, $g^2$ and $g^3$ all have different top-left entry (again try proving this). Since a normal subgroup must contain the conjugacy class of every element in it, we know that the two conjugacy classes of size $13$ are in this subgroup. It now remains to show that some non-identity element of $A$ is in this subgroup. Try finding an appropriate $g$ with $a=3$ or $9$ such that $g^3$ is not the identity (I'll leave this as an exercise). From here, since this normal subgroup contains a non-identity element of $A$, it must contain the entire $A$ (we derived this earlier), and so the subgroup is the entirety of $G$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This piece of writing made it entirely clear. I like the fact you took the time to write it all out in stead of only mathematical symbols. As the text might have given away, I'm new to abstract algebra, and this helps me understand it greatly. Thanks!

Comment: @Mathbeginner No problem, always happy to help!

Comment: I reckon in your third paragraph where you wrote : "Note that if $c \neq 3$,... " but actually meant "Note that if $c \neq 1$,...", right?

Comment: @Mathbeginner Ah, must’ve made a typo. I did mean 1, I’ll fix the answer now.

Comment: That's what I thought, no worries. One more question about the paragraph where you conclude that the remaining elements are in a conjugacy class of $3$. If I get it right, we have $c=1$ at that point and we fix $d$, say $d=1$. Therefore only $a$ is variable and since this has $3$ options, one such class has $3$ elements. But why are there four of this kind?

Comment: We have 12 elements to place into remaining classes, and each class must have 3 elements, so there must be four of this kind so that all 12 elements are taken up.

Comment: Thanks! That makes complete sense now!